# Use of "off" in sentence

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice

I've read this sentence on a story:

> The neon lights and the white sheen off the walls make his eyes look bluer.

Why is "off" used here? Why not "...sheen of the wall..." Would it also work?

Answer (score 2):

In this context "off" refers to the *reflection* of light *off* the wall.

It's not quite correct, since walls should *have* a sheen and not *reflect* a sheen -- the sheen is a quality of the wall's surface.  But this writer might not have thought it through, and anyway it's not that big of a deal.

Similar examples:

> The children bounced the ball **off** the side of the building until the owner made them stop.
>
> I could see her, walking by the cafe, in the reflection **off** the store window

Comment: *Sheen* can mean 'brightness'. For example *And through the drifts the snowy clifts / Did send a dismal sheen*. SamuelTaylor Coleridge, 'The Rime of the Ancient Mariner'

Comment: @Clare  there "sheen" means "shine", as in "the snowy cliffs **shone**".  I would say the sheen *of* the cliffs, but I wouldn't say the sheen *off* the cliffs.  But as I said, it's not a serious distinction.